# Recyclerview pass the data to next item upon deletion of one item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The title seems confusing because I cannot explain this properly using text.

I'll try my best to explain my problem.

Currently I have items in my recyclerview :

[image]

Each item contains a delete button that will remove the item in the recyclerview.

Lets assume that I have 5 items in the list:

what I want to attain is when the user deletes
Item 2
the information/data from item 3 will be transferred to Item 2,

the data from item 4 will be transferred to item 3 and

the data from item 5 will be transferred to item 4

and lastly the item 5 will be deleted.

I currently have no code for this but I'm trying my best to construct it.

Here is my adapter code, it might help:

```
public class CreditCard_PostPayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CreditCard_PostPayAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private static  String TAGedittext = "";
    //private final AccountHistoryTransactionActivity homeActivity;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Integer> mHeaderText;

    CreditCard_PostPayAdapter adapter;
    public CreditCard_PostPayAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Integer> mHeaderTextList ) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mHeaderText = mHeaderTextList;
    }

    @Override
    public CreditCard_PostPayAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.creditcard_postpay_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CreditCard_PostPayAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int pos = position + 1;
        final int mPosition = position;

        if (mHeaderText.size() ==  1) {
            holder.mDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.mDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }
           holder.mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    mHeaderText.remove(mPosition);
                    ArrayList<Integer> temp  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    for (int i = 0 ; mHeaderText.size() - 1 >= i ; i++) {
                        temp.add(i);
                    Log.d("Counter++",""+i);
                    }

                    holder.mMerchantName.setText("");
                    holder.mTransactionAmountEditText.setText("");
                    holder.mTransactionDateEditText.setText("");
                    holder.mPostingDateEditText.setText("");


                    mHeaderText.clear();
                    mHeaderText.addAll(temp);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mHeaderText.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mHeaderTitle
        public ImageView mArrowHeader;
        public ImageButton mDeleteButton;
        public TextInputEditText mTransactionDateEditText,
                mPostingDateEditText,
                mTransactionAmountEditText;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.mHeaderTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header_title);

            this.mDeleteButton = view.findViewById(R.id.mDeleteButton);
            this.mMerchantName = view.findViewById(R.id.mMerchantNameTextView);
            this.mTransactionDateEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.Transaction_date);
            this.mPostingDateEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.posting_date);
            this.mTransactionAmountEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.Transaction_amount);
        }
    }

}
```

My current delete button function is to:

Delete the item(n) and recount all of the remaining item.

Comment: Why you need another `ArrayList` to copy data and put back to main `ArrayList`. Simply removing item from a position and calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` is enough. `Adapter` will automatically reload the `RecyclerView`\

Comment: This is what `RecyclerView` does. Your values are not passed to above element. The thing is the `RecyclerView` moves up the previous items by 1 position so that there isn't any blank space left displayed on the screen.

Comment: Delete the item from arrayList and call notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `onBindViewHolder` method and try,

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CreditCard_PostPayAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mDeleteButton.setTag(position);
    holder.mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int clickedPos = (int) view.getTag();
            mHeaderText.remove(clickedPos);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the passing of data?

Comment: Your code only remove the the item on the list which is already been done in the question.

Comment: When we removes the item next item set to their position. No need to copy paste from temp list.

Comment: @freelancsandroidlovesyou this code not only remove the item but also notify the adapter about the change

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference i got this error

Comment: You're getting a NPE because you're probably not setting your view's tag. You'd need to set mDeleteButton's tag as the position in onBindViewHolder

Comment: Also, don't use notifyDataSetChanged since you're just removing one item; it's a waste. You can use notifyItemRemoved(int position) instead. Plus, you get free animations.

Comment: @stackersoverfllawrerstacking `holder.mDeleteButton.setTag(position);` did you added this line?

Comment: @stackersoverfllawrerstacking So your issue solved??

Comment: i have 4 items in the list, i deleted the item 2 and the item 4 was deleted which is right but then the edittext in my item 2 was cleared instead of item 4.

Comment: You have to save EditText data on list data while update.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the 2nd element. delete the element and remaining will be taken care by recyclerAdapter to remove the row and align the data.

inside your onClickListener, remove the data from ArrayList and the call notifyItemRemoved()

write your onClick inside ViewHolder class

```
onClick(View view){
        mHeaderText.remove(getAdapterPosition());
        notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
}
```

i hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

you an delete the  item in list and refresh your adapter by just doing this  in your onClick:

```
holder.mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                               mHeaderText.remove(position);
                               notifyItemRemoved(position);
                               notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mHeaderText.size());

            }
        });
```